# Truncated sinusoidal signal

Tags: matlab, plot, signals

I want to plot a truncated sinusoidal signal. What I tried is:

```
tstep = 0.1;
t = -1:0.05:2;
f0 = 1;
fi = 10;
t = 0:tstep:2;
s = sin(2*pi*f0*t+fi);
plot(t,s);
```

I have to obtain something like this (for `f0 = 1`):

[image: correct graphic]

---

The text of the problem is:

> Write a Matlab program that plots a truncated sinusoidal signal:
>   `s(t) = PT (t) sin (2πf0t + φ)`
>       where:
>       `T = 1` fixed
>       `f0` is an integer number between `1` and `10` input from GUI (keyboard)
>       `φ` is a randomly generated phase between `0` and `2π` radiants

Comment: There may be other problems as well but your `fi = 10`, it is supposed to be randomly generated in between ***0 and 2π*** as per your question statement. Also this line doesn't do anything: `t = -1:0.05:2;` since you invalidate it after couple of lines by storing different values in `t` and please google how to take screenshots

Comment: Yes, is randomly generated. But, I put fi static... I tried with with many values for fi (0,  1, 5, 10), but I think that I am doing someting wrong with `PT (t)` (I suppose that is 1)..

Comment: I meant `10 ∉ [0,2π]`. What is `PT`?

Comment: `PT(t)` is rectangular signal.

Comment: I google for truncated sinusoidal signal and I find that is equal with `s (t) = APT (t) sin (2π0t)` where APT is rectangular signal and `sin (2π0t)` is sinusoidal signal.

Comment: In the problem statement in your question, you wrote `T=1 fixed`, did you mean `PT=1 fixed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `fi=10`. `fi` is supposed to be randomly generated in between `0` and `2π` as per your question statement. Also this line doesn't do anything: `t = -1:0.05:2;` since you redefine `t` after couple of lines. For generating the rectangular pulse, you can use [`pulstran`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pulstran.html) (requires Signal Processing Toolbox). Complete code with the fixes is below:

```
tstep=0.005;     t=-1:tstep:2;      fi = 2*pi*rand(1);
%Loop to take f0 as an integer number between 1 to 10 input from keyboard
while 1
    f0 = input('f0 = ');  %requesting user input
    if mod(f0,1) || f0<1 || f0>10
       %mod checks whether the value is not an integer and then we check 
       %if it doesn't belong to [1,10]
       disp('Wrong value entered. Please enter an integer between 1 to 10');
    else, break;  %break if the correct value is entered
    end
end

PT = pulstran(t,0.5,'rectpuls');  %Generating rectangular pulse
SW = sin(2*pi*f0*t+fi);           %Generating sinusoidal wave

%I have added two plots just so you know what's happening
subplot(1,2,1); 
plot(t, PT, t, SW, 'linewidth', 2);
legend({'Rectangular Pulse','Sinusoidal Wave'},'location','northoutside','NumColumns',2);
xlabel('Time (t)');    ylabel('Signals');

subplot(1,2,2);
y = PT.*SW;
plot(t, y, 'linewidth', 2);
legend('Truncated Sinusoidal Wave','location','northoutside');
xlabel('Time (t)');    ylabel('s(t)');
```

Result when `fi=pi` and `f0=1`:

[image: result]